# How to connect to network without using network connection icon?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line

Sometimes when I want to connect to network, the icon for connecting in windows hangs and doesn't work.I must restart for activating the icon:

[image]

I go to control panel/network and sharing , but yet from there I cannot do anything.

Is there any script, cmd command or any thing like it, to connect to a network without going in the way described?

also is there any way other than restart to active the icon?

my windows is windows 7.

Comment: What Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening with my system, i was using win 7 - Ultimate -32 bit. I am not sure that i'll work on your system too, but i am letting you know what i have done to resolve this issue. I have installed CCleaner and run this application, go to registry tab in this application and click on "Scan issues" button then it will start scanning and open a list of issues. now click on "Fixed selected issue" and then it will fix all issues. Just restart your machine and you will see that you issue has been resolved. 
   Basically this issue which you are facing is coming because of some registry issues which can be fixed by this CCleaner application. 
    Hope it will also fix your issue too.